# Special style - material icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons, material-design

I want to create a special style like this:

[image]

using HTML and the material icons style by [materialize.css](https://materializecss.com/icons.html).

What I came up with is this html code:

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<p style="font-size: 6.5vh">
  O
  <i style="font-size: 3.8vh;" class="material-icons">bug_report</i>
  <i style="font-size: 3.8vh;" class="material-icons">bug_report</i>
  <span style="">ps!</span>
</p>
```

I got some problems because the "bug-icons" are not aligned at the bottom of the font *(try to make them bigger -you'll see it)*. Another problem is that the space between the text and the icons is way to big.

I tried to add "margin-left: -4%" to the icons what is working for mobile devices but on my desktop it looks like this:

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the problem with the space inbetween the characters there are several ways to solve this (See [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for details). Your main problem here is that every linebreak is interpreted as a whitespace. A simple solution is to just not use any linebreaks and write your HTML in one single line.

For your second problem with the alignment of the icons within the text, you can take a look over [here](https://css-tricks.com/tips-aligning-icons-text/). For our example `position: relative; top: 4px;` should do the job.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: blue;
}
.material-icons {
  font-size: 3.8vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<p style="font-size: 6.5vh">
  O<i class="material-icons">bug_report</i><i class="material-icons">bug_report</i><span>ps!</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set font size by js.

note: probably there are more convenient css solutions.

```js
var p_oops=document.getElementById('p_oops')
var bug_reports=document.getElementsByClassName('bug_report')

var main_ratio=.05;
var i_ratio=.6;
function SetFontSize(){
p_oops.style.fontSize=window.innerWidth*main_ratio+'px';

 for(var i=0, len=bug_reports.length; i<len; i++)
    {
bug_reports[i].style.fontSize=window.innerWidth*main_ratio*i_ratio+'px';
    }

}
SetFontSize();
window.onresize=function(){
   SetFontSize();
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<p id="p_oops">
  O
  <i  style="font-size: 3.8vh;" class="material-icons bug_report">bug_report</i>
  <i style="font-size: 3.8vh;" class="material-icons bug_report">bug_report</i>
  <span style="">ps!</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with `inline-flex`

```
p{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

you can also try `align-items: baseline;`

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: blue;
}
p{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<p style="font-size: 6.5vh">
  O
  <i style="font-size: 3.8vh;" class="material-icons">bug_report</i>
  <i style="font-size: 3.8vh;" class="material-icons">bug_report</i>
  <span style="">ps!</span>
</p>
```